# SystemInit function ends up at add odd address in Kiel ARM compiler

Tags: arm, stm32

I'm seeing some weird behaviour in the Kiel compiler. This is the reset code, I'm using a generic STM32F103C8 board (which uses an M3 core), and the SystemInit function (which is provided by the Kiel libraries) has somehow ended up at an odd address (0800043D), you can see from the screenshot below that the pointer at 080001F8 contains this value and sure enough, when the instruction at the PC (BLX r0) is executed, a hard fault occurs. Has anyone seen this happen before? How can I get it to put the SystemInit function at an even address?

Also, my main() function seems to have ended up at an odd address as well... Shouldn't the compiler align these for me?

These 2 lines from the map file are interesting:

```
0x08000000   0x000000ec   Data   RO         1224    RESET               startup_stm32f10x_md.o
0x080000ec   0x00000008   Code   RO         1269  * !!!main             c_w.l(__main.o)
```

[image: Bug?]

Comment: What is the value of `r0` just before `BLX r0` is executed?

Comment: 0800043D, which is loaded from 080001F6

Comment: These lines from the map file are interesting:

    0x08000000   0x000000ec   Data   RO         1224    RESET               startup_stm32f10x_md.o
    0x080000ec   0x00000008   Code   RO         1269  * !!!main             c_w.l(__main.o)

Comment: And what do you see when you view this memory address as source code?

Comment: added them to the question for formatting

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Can't really disassemble at an odd address, it looks like random instructions, but the SystemInit function label is at that address -1

Comment: Sorry, my comment about the map file crossed over with your question about disassembly

Comment: Try to manually change `r0` to (what you say is) the correct address right before `BLX r0` is executed. What do you observe now?

Comment: Yep, then it jumps to SystemInit correctly

Comment: What is the equivalent C code for those two assembly lines (if you happen to have it)? Can you please search `SystemInit` in the map file, and say what you see next to it? Note that it might appear in more than one place.

Comment: [Any](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15764833/3156750) [function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14120711/3156750) [address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15045144/3156750) [must](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29381889/3156750) [have](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16079189/3156750) [the](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16647084/3156750) [lsb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37004954/3156750) [set](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28110605/3156750) - that's how Thumb interworking works, and on Cortex-M3, all code must be Thumb. Is what's at 0x0800043c executable code?

Comment: Notlikethat - thanks, if you answer it, I'll accept it

Comment: For the record, the actual problem was that I had a large array of data which was not marked as const, so it was trying to put it in sram, but it didn't fit. A full rebuild threw up the "it won't fit" error, not sure why it didn't show up when doing a normal build.